# Adding custom fields to com_content category

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, category, custom-field

I have a component which mainly deals with Joomla content articles. 
I want to add custom fields to Joomla core category.

Is there any chance to add custom fields into category through a plugin or any other way? Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if the answer provided is what you needed please select it as your chosen answer to remove it from the unanswered questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom fields to the com_content (category? I assume you intend component?):

https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin
https://zunostudios.com/blog/development/203-how-to-add-custom-fields-to-articles-in-joomla

You can add a plugin as described here and then, simply via xml add the fields you desire, take a look here for the field types you can add:

https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

Afterwards, you can add the fields in your template.

Best regards

Edit:
Hmmmm.... or do you intend you want to extend the categories component?
That is also possible, you just have to make a minor modification in the plugin i mentioned above:
Inside the plugins main php file, instead of writing:

```
switch($option) {
        case 'com_contact':
```

write:

```
switch($option) {
        case 'com_categories':
```

That's it  ;-)

Comment: But how is this achieved using core custom fields rather than making your own custom field?

Comment: What do you intend with that? What kind of fields would you like to add?
For standard fields you simply add for instance type="text" in the xml..

Comment: Joomla! has custom fields built in now. You don't need to use XML for article, user, or com_contact you can just use a custom field (confusing because it is the same name as a custom field that you would build yourself).  The new Joomla! com_fields.

Comment: Well, that depends, if you want to use subforms for instance, wich help you adding repeatable content (imagine a team-field for instance, where you can add multiple members), then the xml-plugin method is the option to go..

Comment: At the moment. But I think they have latched fields to be able.to do that